# Switch from a fragment to another

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have a app they use Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment. Is it possible to launch a new Fragment from a "parent" Fragment?

For example Fragment A switch to Fragment B and when you press back from the Fragment B it change for the Fragment A.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will help you.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.your_tab_id, new FragmentClassName())
    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: Before doing replace, you need to check if the fragment already exist.